# How to set clientUserId for a Recipient in DocuSign using the REST API?

Tags: php, json, rest, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a RecipientView to send through an app to the recipients of envelopes that are created. With DocuSign's newer API, this requires a `userName` which is entered by the person who creates the document needed to be signed, an `email` which is just the email of the recipient, and a `clientUserId` which is a sender generated string value that authenticates the recipient as an embedded signer so that a RecipientView can be generated to host the signing ceremony.

DocuSign documentation references that I need to set `clientUserId`, but it doesn't mention **how** to to do this other than when the envelope is created through the API. However, in this scenario, envelopes will be created by DocuSign Admin clients through the templates on the actual web interface, and **not** through the API.

My code to generate the RecipientView is all set up here:

```
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$account_id/envelopes/$envelope_id/views/recipient";

$body = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
              "authenticationMethod" => "None",
              "email" => "$email",
              "userName" => "$name",
              "recipientId" => "$recipientId",
              "clientUserId" => "1000"
);

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 201){
    die('Could not connect to end point: '.mysqli_error($conn));
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];
```

This code **does** work when the embedded signer is the Admin account, but not when the envelope is sent to an actual recipient. The return JSON from DocuSign after this request should be:

```
{
    "url": "example.example.com"
}
```

However, the return I get for recipients that are not the Admin of the DocuSign account is:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the 
               specified envelope."
}
```

I believe not setting `clientUserId` is the reason behind this, since the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) says I need to set `clientUserId` and not just create a value when making the call. How do I set a recipient's `clientUserId` via the REST API?

**UPDATE:** Within this scenario, I will not be the one creating and sending envelopes. That will be done by the clients I have through my app, and the large majority of them will most likely use the web interface to do this, not the API. I do have access to all information regarding the Admin account for each client, including the Integrator Key, Access Tokens, Envelope IDs, Account IDs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Embedded Signing (aka Recipient View) there are two calls you need to make.  Well actually 3 calls including the initial Login API but it sounds like you've got that working so I'll focus on the other two.

**Step #1**:  Create an envelope with an embedded recipient.  When adding the recipient make sure you set their `name`, `email`, `recipientId`, and `clientUserId`.

**Step #2**:  Request the Recipient View of the envelope for your signer.  To do so you need to call the EnvelopeViews: createRecipient API and you must reference the same exact set of values for the recipient that you set in step 1 (i.e. `name`, `email`, `recipientId`, and `clientUserId`)

Check out the [Signing from Within your App](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) API Recipe for a full code sample.

Comment: The mistake I was making was not setting the clientUserId. Since I cannot control that field when the envelope is created, I had to set the clientUserId before making the call for the embedded signer url.

Comment: But how to prevent sending email to the embeded signer when we create envelope via DocuSign website?